# R: Computing a sum for rows which contain the same elements

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame of the type

```
df <- data.frame(1:10,2:11,rep(5,10))
df[10,1:2] <- c(2,1)
> df
       X1.10 X2.11 rep.5..10.
    1      1     2          5
    2      2     3          5
    3      3     4          5
    4      4     5          5
    5      5     6          5
    6      6     7          5
    7      7     8          5
    8      8     9          5
    9      9    10          5
    10     2     1          5
```

From this data frame I would like to find the rows which have the same values in column 1 and column 2, sum up the values in column 3 for these rows, assign one of these rows the sum and then remove the other found rows from the data frame. So for example in df I would like to find rows 1 and 10, compute the sum 5+5, then assign 10 to column 3 on row 1, and finally remove row 10.

```
> df
  X1.10 X2.11 rep.5..10.
1     1     2         10
2     2     3          5
3     3     4          5
4     4     5          5
5     5     6          5
6     6     7          5
7     7     8          5
8     8     9          5
9     9    10          5
```

I cannot use for-loops, because the data set is quite large. What would be an effective solution to this problem?

Comment: That's a lot to do.  Have you tried anything?  And why rows 1 and 10 in your example?  They have different values in the first two columns.

Comment: The order of the columns does not matter, i.e., c(2,1) "==" c(1,2) in this sense. What I just thought I could do is change the order of the columns 1 and 2 so that the smaller values are always in column 1 and the larger in columns 2. Then I could easily find the identical rows (same value in column 1 and 2).

Comment: You can proceed as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388766/pairwise-unique-combinations-ignoring-the-direction) and then use `aggregate`

Comment: you df function does not produce what your df prints. when printing df after running the function, df[10, 2] == "11"

Comment: You were right, I forgot to paste everything. It should now be correct.

Comment: There is a really fast `data.table` [solution to a very similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239649/aggregate-data-table-based-on-condition-in-another-row). You might find it useful to take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `apply()` to sort the rows and `aggregate()` to arrive at your expected output.

```
# Reorder values in first 2 cols and cbind with df[,3]
m <- cbind(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df[,3])

# Sum third column grouped by first and second column
aggregate(m[,3], by = list(m[,1],m[,2]),FUN=sum)
#  Group.1 Group.2  x
#1       1       2 10
#2       2       3  5
#3       3       4  5
#4       4       5  5
#5       5       6  5
#6       6       7  5
#7       7       8  5
#8       8       9  5
#9       9      10  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` function to sort the column1 and column2, then do a `groupby` summary.

```
library(dplyr)
sorted <- t(apply(df, 1, function(row) c(row[-3][order(row[-3])], row[3])))

data.frame(sorted) %>% group_by(X1, X2) %>% mutate(X3 = sum(X3)) %>% unique()
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: X1, X2 [9]

     X1    X2    X3
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1     1     2    10
2     2     3     5
3     3     4     5
4     4     5     5
5     5     6     5
6     6     7     5
7     7     8     5
8     8     9     5
9     9    10     5
```

A `data.table` way to do this would be:

```
library(data.table)
sorted <- t(apply(df, 1, function(row) c(sort(row[-3]), row[3])))
data.table(sorted)[, .(V3 = sum(V3)), .(V1, V2)]

   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  2 10
2:  2  3  5
3:  3  4  5
4:  4  5  5
5:  5  6  5
6:  6  7  5
7:  7  8  5
8:  8  9  5
9:  9 10  5
```

**Data**:

```
structure(list(X1.10 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2), X2.11 = c(2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1), rep.5..10. = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("X1.10", "X2.11", "rep.5..10."), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using base functions:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:9, 2), y = c(2:10, 1), z = rep(5,10))
df$t <- df$x + df$y
df2 <- aggregate(z ~ t, data = df, FUN = sum)
final <- merge(df, df2, by = "t")
final <- final[which(!duplicated(final$t)), ]
final$t <- NULL
final$z.x <- NULL

print(final)
   x  y z.y
1  1  2  10
3  2  3   5
4  3  4   5
5  4  5   5
6  5  6   5
7  6  7   5
8  7  8   5
9  8  9   5
10 9 10   5
```